# How to change max line length for formatter provided by Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat extension in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, formatting

I have the *Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat* extension installed in Visual Studio Code. Among other features, this extension can auto-format java code. I have it set to do this whenever I save the file.

It appears to have the max line length set to 120 characters, but I would like to set it to 80 characters. I have been searching everywhere but I can't figure out where to find the relevant setting.

Is it possible to set the formatter to a different max line length? If so, how?

Comment: i think this isn't possible, and you would have to edit the extension itself

Comment: Ok thanks @chipcoint. That's what I was worried about but make sense.

Answer (score 2):

In **Settings.json**, set

```
"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 79,
```

When code is over the max length, which is 80 now, it will turn to the next line:

[image]

After coding, right click in current .java file and choose **Format Document**, all code will be formatted by the wordWrap setting and the max length will be 80.

Comment: @wristbands. Try my answer and see if it solves your question.

Comment: Sorry but that does not really help solve my problem. I did know that it was possible to wrap text onto the next line if it goes over a certain number of characters. But that's not what I was interested in doing. I wanted to be able to have the Java(TM) by Red Hat extension automatically reformat my text to break it into two lines *in a nice-looking way* once it surpassed 80 characters (it currently reformats at 120 characters). But according to chip coint's comment above, it appears that this is simply not possible unfortunately; it can only be set at 120 characters.

Comment: @wristbands. This feature will be added in next extension update.

Comment: Oh that's great to hear! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

The answers in this GitHub issue fixed it for me: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1709

I particularly liked rgrunber's solution to place the prefs in the .vscode folder:

1. Create `.vscode/settings.prefs` and add the following lines:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit=80
org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.line_length=80
```

2. Update `settings.json`

```
{
    "java.settings.url": ".vscode/settings.prefs"
}
```

I expanded upon it and followed the same pattern for my exported eclipse formatter prefs that I have used for years:

1. Create `.vscode/formatter-settings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<profiles version="21">
    <profile kind="CodeFormatterProfile" name="My Formatter" version="21">
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_ellipsis" value="insert"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_enum_declarations" value="insert"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.parentheses_positions_in_for_statment" value="common_lines"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.new_lines_at_block_boundaries" value="true"/>
...
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

2. Update `settings.json`:

```
{
    "java.settings.url": ".vscode/settings.prefs",
    "java.format.settings.url": ".vscode/formatter-settings.xml"
}
```

If you want it to sync across devices, you could instead reference them from a public github repo (append ?raw=true) and set those uris instead.

```
{
    "java.settings.url": "https://github.com/themarquee/vscode-settings/blob/main/settings.prefs?raw=true",
    "java.format.settings.url": "https://github.com/themarquee/vscode-settings/blob/main/formatter-settings.xml?raw=true"
}
```

Voila! Finally after 2 years my vscode formats how I want it to!

Comment: related docs: https://github.com/eclipse-jdtls/eclipse.jdt.ls/wiki/Language-Server-Settings-&-Capabilities#java-formatter-options -> https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fformatter%2FDefaultCodeFormatterConstants.html

Answer (score 0):

The setting you're looking for is `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit` which is located in your java formatter style XML file.

First open your settings json file and find the `java.format.settings.url` option. It is a file url pointing to the style XML file. Open the XML file for editing.

If you already have an `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit` setting then change it to `80`. If not then paste in the following:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit" value="80"/>
```

You *must* restart vscode for the changes to take effect.

I had the opposite problem to you and wanted to prevent vscode from breaking lines except in extreme cases so I set it to `200`.