# How to stop Visual Studio Code from hard wrapping

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

I've got word wrap off, but VS code performs a HARD wrap on text past around 80 characters when it formats (as it does on a save).  I want to either turn off hard wrapping or control the length at which it happens.
I'm on version 1.85.1 and coding Java. I have several extensions installed (extension pack, intellicode, java language support, language support for Java by Red Hat).  I have no experience modifying JSON files, or creating / using XML files, but willing to try.

Comment: You can point `java.format.settings.url` in **settings ** to a custom XML file that defines your formatter settings. In this file, you can increase the `lineLength` setting to allow longer lines.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66946766/11107541, also the word you're looking for is "hard wrap"